# Compare lists, not exact, looking for at least one matching word and excluding some generic words (like inc & ltd)

Tags: list, compare

New here, so please be gentle.

I need to compare two lists of let's say business names. Problem is, there are slight differences in naming conventions and many won't be an exact match.

Is it possible to compare one list to another and match everything with at least one word the same?

Example:

Jimmy B Ptd Ltd ------     Jimmy B =         MATCH

Radiation Co -------        Radiation  =        MATCH

And ignore any recurring words like "pty" and  "ltd".

Example:

GREEN WORD LTD -----   MOON FACE LTD    = NO MATCH

Ideally i could be given a list of matches and scan through them.

Possible for a novice??

Thanks!!

Comment: in what programming language?

Comment: If I could do it in excel that would ideal. Otherwise I could probably manage R. 

Thanks

Comment: Anyone out there?